# How should 3rd party bundles be wrapped in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, architecture, bundle

If I add a 3rd party bundle, say from [Knp bundles](http://knpbundles.com/) for example, should I wrap it first or should I use it directly in my code?

If I decide to wrap it, where do I put the wrapping code? In a separate new bundle? In my application bundle?

To clarify:

I'm not asking about how to add a thirds party bundle to my project.
I'm not asking what a bundle is.

This question is aimed at encapsulating 3rd party code behind wrapper classes. Since the bundle was developed by a 3rd party developer it is a subject for unexpected changes that could break my code.

How do you wrap a 3rd party bundle after adding it to your project?

Comment: When you say "wrap", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I recommend you to look at https://packagist.org/

Comment: In some cases I will fork a 3rd party repository.  Especially FOSUserBundle which I find to be very unstable.  You then adjust your composer file to use the forked version thus ensuring the code does not change on you.

Comment: @Cerad Forking a bundle is only really necessary if you want to change core behaviour. Most likely you would just fix the bundle to a version that you think is stable, might it be like `"vendor/bundle": "1.0.2"` or by adding the commit hash like `"vendor/bundle": "dev-master#{commitHash}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is an answer for 3rd party bundles included via `composer` in Symfony2 in general, it does not refer to a special bundle.*

## First of all

As long as you are fixing the version of the requested bundle to a stable version (like `1.*`) in your `composer.json` (and as long as the developer follows his own guide lines), you shouldn't have any problems with compatibility breaks of the interfaces, thus wrapping is not necessary.

But I'm assuming that you want to prevent any code breaks by throwing Exceptions in the wrapper code and/or implementing fallbacks, so that everything that uses the wrapper code could still work or at least display appropriate errors.

## If you *want* to wrap

If you want to use the `dev-master` version of a given 3rd party bundle, major changes might occur. But there shouldn't be a case where you *really want* to include the `dev-master` when there are stable versions.

Anyway, there are two ways that I see, that could make sense in the case that you want to include the `dev-master` or want to wrap it to display errors, log them, catch exceptions etc.:

### Build a single service class that uses all instances of the services of the 3rd party bundle

This service class could be in one of your bundles that uses the 3rd party bundle, there's no need for an extra bundle in this approach.

This way you have a single service like `acme.thirdparty.client` that wraps single method calls of other services. You would need to inject all 3rd party services that you need (or create instances of the desired sub classes) and wrap all desired method calls.

```
# src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    acme.thirdparty.wrapper.class: Acme\MyBundle\Service\WrapperClass

services:
    acme.thirdparty.wrapper:
        class: %acme.thirdparty.wrapper.class%
        arguments:
            someService: @somevendor.somebundle.someservice
            someOtherService: @somevendor.somebundle.someotherservice
```

And the service class:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Service;

use SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteService;
use SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\OtherConcreteService;

class WrapperClass
{
    private $someService;

    private $someOtherService;

    public function __construct(ConcreteService $someService, OtherConcreteService $someOtherService)
    {
        $this->someService = $someService;
        $this->someOtherService = $someOtherService;
    }

    /**
     * @see SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteService::someMethod
     */
    public function someMethod($foo, $bar = null)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return $this->someService->someMethod();
    }

    /**
     * @see SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteOtherService::someOtherMethod
     */
    public function someOtherMethod($baz)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return $this->someOtherService->someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

You could then add some error handling to those method calls (like catching all exceptions and log them etc.) and thus prevent any code outside of the service class to break. But needless to say, this does not prevent any unexpected behaviour of the 3rd party bundle.

or you could:

### Create a bundle that has multiple services, each wrapping a single service of the 3rd party bundle

A whole bundle has the advantage of being more flexible on what you exactly want to wrap. You could wrap a whole service or just single repositories and replace the wrapped classes with your own ones. The DI container allows the overriding of injected classes, like the following:

```
# src/Acme/WrapperBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    somevendor.somebundle.someservice.class: Acme\WrapperBundle\Service\WrapperClass
```

By overriding the class parameter `somevendor.somebundle.someservice.class` all services that use this class are now instances of `Acme\WrapperBundle\Service\WrapperClass`. This wrapper class could be either extending the base class:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\WrapperBundle\Service;

use SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteService;

class WrapperClass extends ConcreteService
{
     /**
      * @see ConcreteService::someMethod
      */
     public function someMethod($foo, $bar = null)
     {
         // Do stuff here
         parent::someMethod($foo, $bar);
         // And some more stuff here
     }
}
```

... or could use an instance of the original class to wrap it:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\WrapperBundle\Service;

use SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteServiceInterface;
use SomeVendor\SomeBundle\SomeService\ConcreteService;

class WrapperClass implements ConcreteServiceInterface
{
    private $someService;

    /**
     * Note that this class should have the same constructor as the service. 
     * This could be achieved by implementing an interface
     */
    public function __construct($foo, $bar)
    {
        $this->someService = new ConcreteService($foo, $bar);
    }

     /**
      * @see ConcreteService::someMethod
      */
     public function someMethod($foo, $bar = null)
     {
         // Do stuff here
         $this->someService->someMethod($foo, $bar);
         // And some more stuff here
     }
}
```

**Note that implementing an interface for a class that is overriding another one might be mandatory. Also the second one might not be the best idea, since then it's not very clear that you are actually wrapping the `ConcreteService` and not just replacing it. Also this is ignoring the whole idea of Dependency Injection.**

This approach needs a lot more work and means a lot more testing, but if you want more flexibility, this is the way to go.

Perhaps there already are wrapper bundles for your desired 3rd party bundles around (like the `SensioBuzzBundle` for the `Buzz Browser`), in this case, you could porbably use those instead of writing everything yourself.

## Conclusion

Trusting the developer and including a stable version (like `1.*` for bugfixes and new features or `1.0.*` for bugfixes only) is the way to go. If there are no stable versions or if you want to include the `dev-master`, wrapping is an option. If you want to wrap your code, building an extra bundle is the more flexible way, but a single service class could be enough if there's not much code to wrap.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for this bundle is available in the Resources/doc
directory of the bundle:

Read this it is easy to use.

add your bundle into /vendor/bundles
Add the following  namespace entries to the registerNamespaces call in your autoloader:
// app/autoload.php

or  Configure the bundle in
app/config/config.yml